# Java HtmlUnit background JavaScript loading

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, htmlunit

I have a website I'm trying to navigate using HtmlUnit.

This website changes certain buttons/makes certain  elements visible/hidden based on JavaScript events.

The simplest example I can give: there is a text input box and a button with a class on it that prevents it from being clicked. As soon as text is written in the box the button becomes clickable. I am setting the value of the input text box but am not seeing the updates on the button.

I have tried the following in order to make the page wait for background updates:

- use NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController() as the web client's ajax controller
- override processSynchron() to return true when setting ajax controller
- putting the thread to sleep a few seconds
- synchronising on the page variable and calling wait on it for a few seconds
- calling waitForBackgroundJavaScript on the web client
- looping while the page's enclosing window's job manager has no more JavaScript jobs

Comment: Please provide your code how you update the text box and how you retrieve the page content

Comment: HtmlInput form; form.setValueAttribute("..."); then the page content I've tried both checking the Page as a result of button.click() and also the initial object. Maybe this is the issue, not getting the content the right way? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a really low level method.
Try

- using the type("...") method
- then waitForBackgroundJavaScript() to wait for the javascript to process

If this does not help you have to provide a detailed sample to give us a chance to see your code and do some analysis/debugging.